# Display tables in output continuously in SAS

Tags: sas, output

Just got started in SAS yesterday, and I am not comfortable and familiar about SAS compared with R. The one thing is I don't know how to display several tables continuously in output. Every time I scroll up and down, the output interface just disturb the results. For a simple example:

```
title 'Exam results';
data my;
input name $ sex $ math english;
avg = math*0.5 + english/120*100*0.5;
cards;
josh male 89 90
chris male 97 78
lily female 79 92
;
run;
proc print;run;
proc sort data=my;
by descending avg;
run;
proc print;run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, each PROC starts a new page, with titles and all. I suggest leaving it as is. The output window should not be confused with line-by-line listing: it is a document-oriented output so pagination is OK.

BTW, the guys in your data are already sorted by descending average score, so there should be no difference in the outputs.

If you still want your PROC outputs at the same page an OK with e.g. RTF output, adding the following line before the first PROC PRINT will make SAS to continue with the page:

```
ods rtf startpage= no;
```

AFAIK it does not work with listing (text file) destination;
you can further specify the file SAS prints the outputs to

```
ods rtf file= "<you/file/here.rtf>" startpage= no;
```

Please note by default SAS outputs titles and footnotes to RTF header and footer area.
You might also want to suppress other output destinations by adding

```
ods html close;
```

or

```
ods listing close;
```

and enable it back at the end by e.g.

```
ods listing;
```